How to best remove this branch from the apple tree?
What would be the best way to remove this broken branch from the apple tree? The wound looks pretty deep, and I want to try and prevent the wound from getting infected with disease/pests and keep the rest of the tree alive. Would it be best to cut off the entire branch (at the red line) since the other part of the branch is already dead? Also, after removing the branch, how should I best take care of it? Thanks for the help!



Not your question, but still: it seems you have only one main branch left that’s also going to put a lot of strain to the fracture area considering the geometry? You may want to think about replacing the entire tree in the near future.

@Stephie Someone might be able to cut that to a stump, and graft in one or more varieties of apple. But this is the absolute worst time of the year to try it, I think. Probably should cut both bad branches, and leave the third up til winter so it has some foliage. Some of the orchard trees that get that graft look pretty nice just a couple years after.

@JohnO I'm looking to try to keep the tree alive for now, but yeah not sure the main branch can handle the strain. So cutting both branches off then grafting later in springtime would be best? Thanks!!

That remaining branch looks pretty precarious to me. But it wouldn't have to live forever, just keep the stump/roots from dying for the rest of the year. Then later when it gets colder (optimum time depends alot on where you are, climate zone), you'd saw it off below all the branches. Decent hand saw, not chainsaw. You'd carefully split the trunk vertically, and wedge one or more grafts into the splits. Some people also use wax to help seal those. Could likely find someone who could do it for you (I've only tried grafting apple in a horticulture class, didn't do well), most likely. Good luck.
